# How to identify the first sign change in a sequence of list using python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the below list - python

[1,3,2,3,5,-6,-3,-4,-3,-5,6,7,8,9,-6,-4,-5,-8]

I want to take décision statement when en countering positive or negative for the first time

Ex -6 , 6 and -6 all the 3 places I want décision statement

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand what you are asking. Please add what you've tried even if it didn't work.

Comment: On any given list I want get the first sign change.  Count=0 for number in numbers : if num < 0 : count +=1

Comment: do you want where? or just the values? a[1:][np.diff(np.sign(a)) != 0]
... array([-6,  6, -6])  where `a` is the array version of your list

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do something when the sign changes. I'm going to assume it's some function called `f`. So, in broad strokes, we want code that looks like (call your list `l`):

```
for x in l:
    if (the sign changed at x):
        f()
```

What does the sign changing mean? Well, either `l[i] > 0` and `l[i-1]` < 0 or vice versa, and you'll have to decide what to do when one of the numbers is `0`. So suppose you write a function called `sign_change(x,y)` that returns `True` when the signs of `x` and `y` are different and `False` when they're the same.

Note that this doesn't quite go with the pseudocode above--we need access to both the current element and the previous element. So, rather than iterating over the list, iterate over the indices, from `1,..., len(l)-1`. This gives us:

```
for i in range(1, len(l) - 1):
    if sign_change(l[i], l[i-1]):
        f()
```

We have to start iterating at 1 because there's nothing before `0`. (And, in fact, `l[-1]` will give us the *last* element of the list.)

Now you just have to write `f` and `sign_change`.

Answer (score 1):

This one detects the sign change and return numbers whose signs are changed:

```
lst =[1,3,2,3,5,-6,-3,-4,-3,-5,6,7,8,9,-6,-4,-5,-8]
print(' '.join([str(y) for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if (x ^ y) < 0]))
# -6 6 -6
```

If you want the count of times sign is changed:

```
lst =[1,3,2,3,5,-6,-3,-4,-3,-5,6,7,8,9,-6,-4,-5,-8]
print(len([str(y) for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if (x ^ y) < 0]))
# 3
```